# Validation rule error messages appear on custom page without adding to page

Tags: validation-rule

I have few validation rules on an object. These rules are configured to show error message next to the field. I capture data to create a record of this object in a form (vf page). This page has a pageMessage element and a Save button. Method called on save button click inserts the record. If there are any errors from validation rules, they show up in the pagemessage component without having to explicitly add to page using ApexPage.addMessage. If i change the validation rule to show error message on top of page, validation error messages do not show up. How do i suppress the error messages on the VF page without changing the position of error message in the validation rule? I am trying to show different error message from the one configured in the validation rule. The method - handleBusinessExceptions(eDML) does this for me. So i want to suppress messages from my validation rule and show custom messages in its place.Right now i get both the standard and custom error messages.(See first and last message in screenshot)[image]

Snippet from Save method:

```
        Database.SaveResult saveAccountResult;

        try {

            // Upsert Account object
            saveAccountResult = Database.update(accountObj);
        }
        catch(DmlException eDML){           
            handleBusinessExceptions(eDML);
            return null;
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.debug('---->Account update error' + e);
            ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,e.getMessage()));
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: Can you add a screenshot for better clarify of your question

Comment: Why would you want to design it this way? IMO it doesn't make any sense to bypass your validations, letting garbage data in.

Comment: @Oleksiy.. editing my question to add more details..

Comment: Possible duplicate of answer in: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/136563/is-it-possible-to-show-standard-and-custom-error-message-at-the-same-time

Comment: @Eric- problem is i am able to see both my custom and standard error messages..

Comment: @SantanuBoral - attached screenshot of error message component on my page